# Apple Watch and iphone communication

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I am implementing apple watch app with in my existing app.I need to full fill these task between both iphone and watch

**1)** sending data from watch to iphone Done (by using openParentApplication).

**2)** getting call back also done (using openParentApplication call back method)

**3)** I need to get apple watch notify when user click on a button on iphone app .I have implemented reverse functionality using openParentApplication.

**I stuck how to update apple watch UI after user click on any button or any particular task happen on iphone app.**

**Please let me know is there any way to perform passing event and data from iphone to apple watch**

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole for communication between iphone and watchKit.

Comment: Thanks , lets try with this

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout the new WCSessionDelegate is watchOS 2.0. It can be implemented on both the Apple Watch and contains multiple methods for sending data back and forth between the two devices. Detailed information can be found in the WWDC video [Introducing Watch Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=713)